# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_r * \mathbb{Z}_s$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G=A*B$ where $A=\langle a \mid a^r \rangle$, $B = \langle b \mid b^s \rangle$. Describe the automorphisms of $G$.

**TL;DR** Is there an elegant way to answer the above question?

I showed that if $r \neq s$ then the automorphisms of $G$
are exactly those $\rho \in \operatorname{End}(G)$ with
$\rho(a)=g^{-1} a^n g$ and $\rho(b)=g^{-1} b^m g$
where $g \in G$ and $(n,r)=(m,s)=1$.
That is, every automorphism of $G$ is the composition of an inner automorphism
with an automorphism $\phi$ which extends two automorphisms
$\phi_A \in \operatorname{Aut}(A)$,
$\phi_B \in \operatorname{Aut}(B)$
(there is a unique such $\phi$ by the universal property of the free product and it can be easily verified that it is an automorphism).
If $r=s$ we could also compose with the automorphism that swaps $a$ and $b$.

A sketch of my solution for the case $r \neq s$:
Assume $r > s$ and let $\rho \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.
Since $\rho$ has to preserve the order of elements
I showed that $\rho(a)=g^{-1} a^n g$ and $\rho(b)=h^{-1} b^m h$
for some $g,h \in G$ and and $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $(n,r)=(m,s)=1$
(if we had $\rho(b) = h^{-1} a^m h$ then $b$ would not be
in the image of $\rho$; we can see this if we mod out by $a$).
Then I composed $\rho$ with a conjugation with $g^{-1}$ and the appropriate automorphism extending the inverses of
$(x \mapsto x^n) \in \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ and $(x \mapsto x^m) \in \operatorname{Aut}(B)$ to get an automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ such that
$\phi(a) = a$ and $\phi(b)=u^{-1}bu$ for some $u \in G$.
And then I proved that since $b \in \phi(G)$,
$u$ has to be in $\{b^j a^i \mid i,j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
That implies that $hg^{-1} = b^j a^i$ for some $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ as well.
Letting $g':=a^i g$ and $h':=b^{-j}h$ we have that
$\rho(a)=g'^{-1}a^n g'$, $\rho(b):=h'^{-1}b^m h'$ and $g'=h'$.

Although I solved this problem, I think my solution is too long and not very pretty. So my question is, is there a more elegant way to answer the original question?